# $(TargetFramework) macro is not honored in Directory.Build.props file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am using `Directory.Build.props` in my .NET 6 solution, to set common properties for multiple projects. I use MSBuild macros for example: `$(MsBuildProjectName)`, `$(Configuration)`, `$(TargetFramework)`, however the `$(TargetFramework)` is completely disregarded.

Diagnostics: The property setting and the other parts of the path is in effect, so the issue if not about the `Directory.Build .props` is not in effect.

If I use exactly the very same line in the .csproj files, the `$(TargetFramework)` part of the path is correctly honored.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

"TargetFramework" is (typically) defined in the actual `.csproj` file - since you indicate nothing to the contrary in your question, I assume in your case that happens as well.

`Directory.Build.props` is imported very early in the build process, before the content of your `.csproj` files is read. Thus, if you reference any property in there that is (only) defined by your `.csproj` file it will be empty.  `MSBuildProjectName` and others are directly defined by MSBuild itself and thus are also available in `Directory.Build.props`.

You could simulate this effect by simply defining a property `FooBar` in your `.csproj` file and then try to "use" it in `Directory.Build.props`. You will observe it is also not set there.

(Also see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#import-order) for more information.)

(The observed effects could be different if you build for multiple TargetFrameworks. Because then, the outer MSBuild invocation for multiple TFMs will invoke MSBuild for each specified TFM specified in `TargetFrameworks` and passes that as property `TargetFramework` from "outside". Thus, if `Directory.Build.props` is imported then, `TargetFramework` will be defined. But your question doesn't suggest this could be the problem, so I won't go any deeper here.)

Comment: I love you! I've been banging my head for hours until this one. But it all makes sense, good explanation!